# Не могу вызвать функцию из dll в C#

Tags: c#, struct, pinvoke

Пытаюсь вызвать функцию rgethstpar_date из библиотеки Honeywell hscnetapi.dll в C# 4 VS 2010.

```
int rgethstpar_date
(
char* server,
int num_gethsts,
rgethstpar_date_data* gethstpar_date_data
);
```

**Параметры:**

server (in) Name of the server that the database resides on

num_gethsts (in) The number of points passed to rgethstpar_xxxx in the gethstpar_xxxx_data argument

gethstpar_xxxx_data (in/out) Pointer to a series of rgethstpar_xxxx_data structures (one for each point)

**Структура:**

```
/* define structure for RGETHST_DATE procedure call */
struct rgethst_date_data_str
{
    n_ushort        hist_type;
    n_ulong         hist_start_date;
    n_float         hist_start_time;
    n_ushort        num_hist;
    n_ushort        num_points;
    n_ushort        *point_type_nums;
    n_ushort        *point_params;
    n_char          *archive_path;
    n_float         *hist_values;
    n_ushort        gethst_status;
};
```

**Описание структуры:**

uint2 hist_type (in) Defines the type of history to retrieve, this will be one of the standard server history types. Namely using one of the following: HST_1MIN, HST_6MIN, HST_1HOUR, HST_8HOUR, HST_24HOUR, HST_5SECF, HST_1HOURE, HST_8HOURE, HST_24HOURE

uint4 hist_start_date (in) Start date of history to receive in Julian days (number of days since 1st January 1981).

ureal4 hist_start_time (in) Start time of history to retrieve in seconds since midnight.

uint2 num_hist (in) Number of history values per point to be retrieved.

uint2 num_points (in) Number of points to be processed. MAXIMUM value allowed is 20.

uint2* point_type_nums (in) Array (of dimension num_points) containing the point type/numbers of the point history values to retrieve.

uint2* point_params (in) Array of (dimension num_points) containing the parameter numbers of the history values to retrieve.

uchar* archive path (in) Pointer to the NULL-terminated string containing the archive pathname of the archive file. A NULL pointer implies that the system will use current history and any archive files which correspond to the value of the date and time parameters.

real4* hist_values (out) Array (of dimension num_points * num_hist) to provide storage for the returned history values.

uint2 gethst_status (out) Return value of the actual remote gethst_date
call.

Написал тестовый код:

```
[DllImportAttribute("hscnetapi.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, EntryPoint = "rgethstpar_date", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern int rgethstpar_date([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] String server, int num_gethsts, [In, Out] GetArchData[] gethstpar_date_data);

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, Pack = 1)]
public struct GetArchData
{
public UInt16 hist_type;            
public UInt32 hist_start_date;
public float hist_start_time;
public UInt16 num_hist;
public UInt16 num_points;          

[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)]
public UInt16[] point_type_nums;

[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)]
public UInt16[] point_params;

[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
public String archive_path;

[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)]
public float[] hist_values;

public UInt16 gethst_status;

public GetArchData(UInt16 hist_type, UInt32 hist_start_date, float hist_start_time, UInt16 num_hist, UInt16 num_points, UInt16[] point_type_nums, UInt16[] point_params, String archive_path, float[] hist_values, UInt16 gethst_status)
{
this.hist_type = hist_type;
this.hist_start_date = hist_start_date;
this.hist_start_time = hist_start_time;
this.num_hist = num_hist;
this.num_points = num_points;
this.point_type_nums = point_type_nums;
this.point_params = point_params;
this.archive_path = archive_path;
this.hist_values = hist_values;
this.gethst_status = gethst_status;
}
}
string server = "SRV1";
UInt16 hist_type = 3;
DateTime start_date = new DateTime(2017, 05, 29, 04, 00, 00);
UInt32 hist_start_date = (UInt32)start_date.Subtract(new DateTime(1981, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Local)).Days;
float hist_start_time = (float)(start_date.Hour * 60 + start_date.Minute * 60 + start_date.Second);

UInt16[] point_type_nums = new UInt16[1];
point_params[0] = 5582;

UInt16[] point_params = new UInt16[1];
point_params[0] = 32763;

String archive_path = null;
float[] hist_values = new float[20];
UInt16 gethst_status = 0;                       

GetArchData[] gethstpar_date_data = { new GetArchData(hist_type, hist_start_date, hist_start_time, 20, 1, point_type_nums, point_params, archive_path, hist_values, gethst_status) };

status = NativeMethods.rgethstpar_date(server, 1, gethstpar_date_data);
```

Весь код на [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/411eh4EU)

Программа завершается с ошибкой:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.TypeLoadException: Cannot marshal field 'point_type_
nums' of type 'GetArchData': Invalid managed/unmanaged type combination (Array f
ields must be paired with ByValArray or SafeArray).
   at System.StubHelpers.MngdNativeArrayMarshaler.ConvertContentsToNative(IntPtr
 pMarshalState, Object& pManagedHome, IntPtr pNativeHome)
   at netapi_con.Program.NativeMethods.rgethstpar_date(String server, Int32 num_
gethsts, GetArchData[] gethstpar_date_data)
   at netapi_con.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\ExperionAdmin\Documents
\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\netapi_con\netapi_con\Program.cs:line 136
```

Как правильно передать такую структуру в функцию rgethstpar_date из dll?

---

Вариант с ByValArray

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, Pack = 1)]
public struct GetArchData
{
    public UInt16 hist_type;            
    public UInt32 hist_start_date;           
    public Single hist_start_time;
    public UInt16 num_hist;
    public UInt16 num_points;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 1)]            
    public UInt16[] point_type_nums;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 1)]            
    public UInt16[] point_params;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
    public String archive_path;           

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 25)]           
    public Single[] hist_values;

    public UInt16 gethst_status;

    public GetArchData(UInt16 hist_type, UInt32 hist_start_date, Single hist_start_time, UInt16 num_hist, UInt16 num_points, UInt16[] point_type_nums, UInt16[] point_params, String archive_path, Single[] hist_values, UInt16 gethst_status)
    {
        this.hist_type = hist_type;
        this.hist_start_date = hist_start_date;
        this.hist_start_time = hist_start_time;
        this.num_hist = num_hist;
        this.num_points = num_points;
        this.point_type_nums = point_type_nums;
        this.point_params = point_params;
        this.archive_path = archive_path;
        this.hist_values = hist_values;
        this.gethst_status = gethst_status;
    }
}

GetArchData[] gethstpar_date_data = { new GetArchData(hist_type, hist_start_date, hist_start_time, 25, 1, point_type_nums, point_params, archive_path, hist_values, gethst_status) };  

status = NativeMethods.rgethstpar_date(server, 1, gethstpar_date_data);

[DllImportAttribute("hscnetapi.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, EntryPoint = "rgethstpar_datе", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern int rgethstpar_date([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] String server, int num_gethsts, [In, Out] GetArchData[] gethstpar_date_data);
```

Весь код по [ссылке](https://pastebin.com/411eh4EU)

Этот вариант работает:

```
0000    5582    0
status2 - 0022
Date -  13297   14400.00        0
Press any key to continue
```

Но библиотека возвращает неизвестную ошибку 0х22.
У библиотеки есть отладочный лог-файл, и нем видно, что передаются параметры неправильно:

```
02-JUN-2017  18:00:34.342  cd_snd_req:207: AdjustWritePortForNetAPI: Entering
02-JUN-2017  18:00:34.342  cd_snd_req:222: AdjustWritePortForNetAPI: prog (1) is NIF_SERVER_PROG_NO
02-JUN-2017  18:00:34.342  rgethstp.c:648: c_hsc_construct_param_hist_dates_packet_NADSv2(pns=0x4a11be8, num_gethsts=1, gethstpar_date_data2=0x5f9b90);
02-JUN-2017  18:00:34.342  c_hsc_param_hist_dates_push_2:96: c_hsc_param_hist_dates_push_2(sp=4a11be8, hist_type=3, hist_start_date=0, hist_start_time=0.000000,         num_hist=1, num_points=5582, point_type_nums=7ffb0000, point_params=5c47e8, archive_path=(null));
02-JUN-2017  18:00:34.342  c_hsc_param_hist_dates_push_master:135: c_hsc_param_hist_dates_push_master(sp=4a11be8, hist_type=3, hist_start_date=0, hist_start_time=0.000000,         num_hist=1, num_points=5582, point_type_nums=7ffb0000, point_params=5c47e8, archive_path=(null), callMode=2);
02-JUN-2017  18:00:34.342  rgethstp.c:676: c_hsc_param_hist_dates_push_2() failed
02-JUN-2017  18:00:34.342  n_release:55: n_release(sp=4a11be8);
02-JUN-2017  18:00:34.342  rgethstp.c:408: return (errno=34)
```

При запуске тестовой программы на С++ в логе:

```
02-JUN-2017  18:33:55.984  c_hsc_param_hist_dates_push_2:96: c_hsc_param_hist_dates_push_2(sp=31be8, hist_type=3, hist_start_date=13297, hist_start_time=14400.000000,         num_hist=25, num_points=2, point_type_nums=3efca0, point_params=3efc94, archive_path=);
02-JUN-2017  18:33:55.984  c_hsc_param_hist_dates_push_master:135: c_hsc_param_hist_dates_push_master(sp=31be8, hist_type=3, hist_start_date=13297, hist_start_time=14400.000000,         num_hist=25, num_points=2, point_type_nums=3efca0, point_params=3efc94, archive_path=, callMode=2);
```

В первом фрагменте лога дата и время равны нулю, num_points равен нулевому элементу массива point_type_nums. Что-то с выравниванием структуры, а что - понять не могу.

[image: Передаваемая структура с значениями]

---

Переписал на C++\CLR. На C# так и не получилось вызвать функцию.

Comment: Ну, вроде в сообщении об ошибке достаточно ясно сказано, что массив нужно маршалировать с параметром `ByValArray` или `SafeArray`.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, `ByValArray` в данном случае не подходит. В документации указано, что нужен указатель, а `ByValArray` это не указатель а сам массив, встроенный в тело структуры. Ну а `SafeArray` это вообще какая-то COM-штука, не совместимая с обычными C-указателями.